# Ellipse with CombinedGeometry

Tags: wpf, xaml, geometry, ellipse

I have this ellipse:

[image]

```
    <Ellipse Name="backgroundEllipse1" Fill="Pink">
        <Ellipse.Clip>
            <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <EllipseGeometry x:Name="backgroundEllipseMask1" Center="150,150" RadiusX="300" RadiusY="300"></EllipseGeometry>
                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                    <EllipseGeometry x:Name="backgroundEllipseMask2" Center="150,150" RadiusX="130" RadiusY="130"></EllipseGeometry>
                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
            </CombinedGeometry>
        </Ellipse.Clip>
    </Ellipse>
```

How can I make something like this?
[image]

I'm trying to combine the center and Radius values but something escapes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `ArcSegment`

```
<Canvas>
    <Path Stroke="Pink" StrokeThickness="10" >
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="400,400">
                    <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True"
                            Size="100, 100"
                            Point="480, 410"
                            SweepDirection="Counterclockwise" />
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

Note that the arc starts form (400,400) and ends in (480,410). It moves `Counterclockwise` and is a large arc. `Size="100, 100"` determines the size of the `Ellipse` (or Circle if they are equal) [This post](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2008/01/Mathematics-of-ArcSegment.html) can help you.